# Location of python string class in the source code

Tags: python, string, class

I'm looking into overloading the `+` operator for a certain string so I was thinking of subclassing the string class then adding the code in the new class.  However I wanted to take a look at the standard string class first but I can't seem to find it... stupid eh?

Can anyone point the way?  Even online documentation of the source code.

Comment: It may be C Extention, and builtin type so I think its not possible to open the code as .py file what you think...

Comment: "I'm looking into overloading the '+' operator for a certain string".  "overloading" for "a certain string" isn't anything sensible under any circumstances.  You probably want a new class of objects entirely that play well with strings.  You should provide more information, since what you're describing doesn't make much sense.

Comment: well the specific case is overloading the string so that when i add use the __add__ method with a numeric type (int, float, etc), it will 'increment' to the corresponding letter.  e.g.  'A' + 2 = 'C'.  however since i've never done any type of overloading before, i'm also interested in the way operators are overloaded in the general sense, not just in this particular situation.

Comment: "it will 'increment' to the corresponding letter. e.g. 'A' + 2 = 'C'."?  That's not a "string".  That's a "character".  A highly-resticted and specialized class of objects that happens to provide a string result when used with other strings?  Is that what you're talking about?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's documented [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq).   The main implementation is in [`Objects/stringobject.c`](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/stringobject.c).  Subclassing `str` probably isn't what you want, though.  I would tend to prefer composition here; have an object with a string field, and special behavior.

Comment: Link is dead now. See https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/stringobject.c

Comment: And... Link is dead again. I guess the source code is now located on Github, in [`Objects/unicodeobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c).

Answer (score 2):

You might mean this.

```
class MyCharacter( object ):
    def __init__( self, aString ):
        self.value= ord(aString[0])
    def __add__( self, other ):
        return MyCharacter( chr(self.value + other) )
    def __str__( self ):
        return chr( self.value )
```

It works like this.

```
>>> c= MyCharacter( "ABC" )
>>> str(c+2)
'C'
>>> str(c+3)
'D'
>>> c= c+1
>>> str(c)
'B'
```

Answer (score 0):

my implementation is similar, though not as neat:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __add__(self, other):
        for x in range(1, len(self.name)):
            a = list(self.name)[-1 * x]
            return self.name[:len(self.name)-x] + chr(ord(a) + other)


>>> CAA = MyClass('CAA')
>>> CAA + 1
'CAB'
>>> CAA + 2
'CAC'
>>> CAA + 15
'CAP'
```

Comment: "not as neat"?  It's got weird, weird problems.  Why is there a `return` in the middle of of the `for` loop?  That will perform the "loop" exactly once and stop.  There's no actual "loop" going on.  This can be simplified considerably.

Comment: Also, unless you're using Python 3, please make it a subclass of `object`.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a link that is not currently dead in 2020: https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/stringobject.c